# will angular 2 work with visual studio 2012?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2012, npm

I am in the process of creating some documentation for my team to use Angular 2. We are using Visual Studio 2012

if angular 2 works with it. 
- what is the best tool for working with Angular 2.
- From the Angular 2 website, it seems that we need Node.js and npm for working with angular 2. 
- I work in a company where there are two different networks and development happens only in the dev network which does not have any internet. 
- I am not sure how will npm work without internet. Any possible pointers on this would be very helpful.

I did a lot of research on these and did not seem to find any proper documentation on choosing the right path.

Comment: Yes it will work with visual studio 2012. You can checkout the supported tool with `angular 2` [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). Its depend on requirement which tool will be used.

Comment: You...don't let your devs use the internet?? :|

Comment: yes unfortunately !!

Comment: I have gone through the link you have mentioned above for typescript. Visual studio 2012 is not in the list !!

Comment: No matter what IDE you use, I really don't see how you can develop code efficiently (especially web development) without using the internet. Not being able to use NPM is just one example

Comment: thanks @yarons, I get your point but thats how my company works. Is there a possibility of a work around ?

Comment: Eventually, you will need to get those dependencies from somewhere. You don't have to use NPM, and I'm sure Angular's dependencies exist on some CDN somewhere. You can download the relevant JS files (using a computer that is connected to the internet...) and just copy them to some `lib` folder in your project.